# Find the maximum and minimum of the function $f$

Tags: calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Find the maximum and minimum of $f(x, y)=xy-y+x-1$ at the set $x^2+y^2\leq 2$.

I have done the following:

Since the region $x^2+y^2\leq 2$ is closed, $f$ has a maximum and a minimum,  which is either at the boundary or at the critical points of the function.

To find the critical points we do the following:

$$\nabla f=\overrightarrow{0} \Leftrightarrow (y+1, x-1)=(0, 0) \Rightarrow x=1, y=-1$$

So, we have that the only critical point is $(1, -1)$, which satisfies the contraint.

To find the extremas of $f$ at the boundary $x^2+y^2=2$, we will use Lagrange multipliers therem.

The constraint is $g(x, y)=x^2+y^2-2=0$.

We are looking for $x$, $y$ and $\lambda$ such that $$\nabla f(x, y)=\lambda \nabla g(x, y) \tag 1$$ and $$g(x, y)=0  \tag 2$$

$$(1) \Rightarrow (y+1, x-1)=\lambda (2x, 2y) \Rightarrow \lambda =\frac{1}{2}$$ 
$$\Rightarrow x=y+1$$

$$(2) \Rightarrow y=\frac{-1+\sqrt{3}}{2}, y=\frac{-1-\sqrt{3}}{2}$$

SO, the extremas are the points $\left (\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2}, \frac{-1+\sqrt{3}}{2}\right )$ and $\left (\frac{1-\sqrt{3}}{2}), \frac{-1-\sqrt{3}}{2}\right )$.

Calculating the values of $f$, we have: $$f\left (\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2}, \frac{-1+\sqrt{3}}{2}\right )=\frac{1}{2} \\ f\left (\frac{1-\sqrt{3}}{2}), \frac{-1-\sqrt{3}}{2}\right )=\frac{1}{2} \\ f(1, -1)=0$$

SO, $f$ has a local maximum at the points $\left (\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2}, \frac{-1+\sqrt{3}}{2}\right )$ and $\left (\frac{1-\sqrt{3}}{2}), \frac{-1-\sqrt{3}}{2}\right )$ and an absolute minimum at $(1, -1)$.

Is this correct?? Could I improve something??

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to check the answer you get from the Lagrange multipliers, you could look for "extrema" along the boundary of the region by looking at the map:

$$F: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb R$$
$$F(t) = f(\gamma(t)) = f(\sqrt{2} \cdot cos(t), \sqrt{2} \cdot sin(t)), t \in [0, 2\pi]$$

Which is a function on one variable relating every point in the boundary to its corresponding "height" in the graph of $z = f(x, y)$.

The resulting function is:

$$F(t) = f(\gamma(t)) = 2 \cdot cos(t) \cdot sin(t) - \sqrt{2} \cdot sin(t) + \sqrt{2} \cdot cos(t) - 1$$

From here you may find its derivative, etc. with all the tools from functions in one variable.

(To get $\gamma(t)$ you just parametrize the boundary of the region using the identity $cos(t) + sin(t) = 1$.)

I hope this helps, I find it useful to be able to check this sort of problem with a "1D version", so to speak.

Comment: PS.: for a quick "visual check" you could just plot this function in WolframAlpha, etc. without having to resort to any "rigorous" analysis

Answer (score -1):

Looks good, I have just a few comments:

"So the extras are the points..." at this point we don't know which of these is an extremum. These are *possible* extreme points. It is only *after* we plug in all the values that we know which are extrema.

"$f$ has a maximum and minimum" I would phrase as "$f$ achieves its maximum and minimum"